# The operation couldn’t be completed. Application info provider (FBSApplicationLibrary) returned nil for "io.dopple.Dopple"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

After updating Xcode to its newest version I can no longer run my app on my physical iPhone 11 device. As soon as it completes building I keep getting the error "The operation couldn’t be completed. Application info provider (FBSApplicationLibrary) returned nil for "io.dopple.Dopple"
". These are the details it provides me:

```
Could not launch “Dopple”
Domain: IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain
Code: 3
Failure Reason: The operation couldn’t be completed. Application info provider (FBSApplicationLibrary) returned nil for "io.dopple.Dopple"
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2021-12-31 20:56:37 +0000";
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 855031;
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = DBGLLDBLauncher;
    RawUnderlyingErrorMessage = "The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. Application info provider (FBSApplicationLibrary) returned nil for \"io.dopple.Dopple\"";
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone11,8";
    "device_osBuild" = "15.1 (19B74)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 82446;
    "operation_errorCode" = 3;
    "operation_errorDomain" = IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain;
    "operation_errorWorker" = DBGLLDBLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 5;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_runnable_swiftVersion" = "5.5.2";
    "param_runnable_type" = 2;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos15.2";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "15.2";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 12.0.1 (Build 21A559)
Xcode 13.2.1 (19586) (Build 13C100)
Timestamp: 2021-12-31T12:56:37-08:00
```

What should I do?

Comment: @Fogmeister Yes

Comment: Can you try deleting the app from your phone. Also, what version is your phone on?

Comment: @Fogmeister I already tried deleting but it still won't work. Also my phone is on iOS 15.1

Comment: Also… restarting the device seemed to help here… https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/670489

Comment: @Fogmeister I'll give restarting the phone a shot. I'll update on what happens thx.

Comment: @Fogmeister Thanks a lot it worked!

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this link… https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/670489

It looks like restarting the device might solve this.

Comment: Restart fixed it :)